# Why is this Cayley diagram valid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading *A Book of Abstract Algebra* by Charles C. Pinter to give me an introduction to the topic, but one of the exercises has me confused. The following Cayley diagram is shown: [image]

But I can't understand why this isn't invalid - isn't each vertex connected to two vertices which represent the same element of of the group since the lines are all of the same type and undirected?

I'm sure the diagram is valid since it features on the front cover of the book!

Comment: Is it for finite cyclic group of order 6?

Comment: @Sigur If the sides were directed then I would assume this was the case - the book specifies that the undirected edges imply the element being multiplies by is its own inverse so cannot be an order 6 cyclic group.

Comment: Have you sure you've got the picture right? In my version on the book (second edition, p.52), half the edges are dashed; this means that the group is *not* cyclic, but dihedral (generated by two involutions).

Comment: Oh, I see that on page 99, there is the Cayley graph you mention (alongside the dashed version). In that case it is true that the edges should all be directed consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- you're partially correct! Each edge represents *multiplying by the same generator (element)* but each vertex represents a ***different*** element of the group. So this particular diagram represents the group $C_6$ (some people write it as $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})$ or $\mathbb{Z}_6$). This group consists of six elements:

$$C_6=\{ [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5] \}$$

and has the binary operation of *addition modulus 6*, that is, $[1]+[3]=[4]$ but $[2]+[4]=[0]$, since $1+3 \equiv 4 \ (\text{mod} \ 6)$ but $2+4 \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ 6)$.

Anyways, this group has a special property concerning the element $[1]$. Particularly, we can represent every element in the group with $[1]$! Let's let $[1]$ be $x$. Then:

$x^0 = [1]^0 = [0] = e$

$x^1 = [1]$

$x^2 = [1] + [1] = [2]$

$x^3 = [1] + [1] + [1] = [3]$

...

$x^5 = [1] + [1] + [1] + [1] + [1] = [5]$

$x^6 = [1] + [1] + [1] + [1] + [1] + [1] = [6] = [0] = e = x^0$.

Now let's get back to the diagram. In the diagram, let one vertex be $e$. Then, traveling (lets say "counterclockwise" here) along a path is the same as multiplying by $x$ (that is, by $[1]$). As a result, here is what our diagram looks like:

[image: xxxx]

So going picking any point in this diagram and going counterclockwise represents multiplying by $x$ whenever you go over an edge, that is, starting at $x^3$ for example and moving counterclockwise over two edges represents the element $x^3 \cdot x \cdot x = x^5 = [5] \in C_6$. Similarly, moving *clockwise* is the same as multiplying by $x^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure a Cayley diagram is an undirected graph whenever the group it's representing is commutative, but I haven't touched Cayley diagrams in quite some time so uhhh.. I'll wait for someone else to come along and check me on that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think the problem is that the book has strayed from the convention it established earlier in the chapter where an edge without a direction represents multiplying by an element which is its own inverse (as opposed to here where it seems to mean you can pick either direction as long as you pick for all elements) - I think you are right that this is what is intended by the author :)

Comment: @acernine Glad I can help! There are some cases (as the other person mentioned) where some edges represent multiplying by a particular element and others represent a different element. Usually this is clarified with different colored edges (e.g. moving along red edges is multiplying by some element $x$ but moving along green edges is multiplying by some element $y$). Perhaps even they'll do something like solid edges versus dashed edges, and so on, but you'll cross that road when you get to it. Happy studying!

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on the book's definition of "Cayley diagram".

If the pair $(G,S)$ is such that $S=S^{-1}$ (meaning if $s\in S$ then $s^{-1}\in S$), then the information contained in the direction of the edges is redundant (since for every arrow $a\to b$ there is an arrow $b\to a$). Also although coloring each edge obtained by $s\in S$ makes it apparent which generator is responsible for the edge, a lot of the times that information is not very useful.

For those reasons in case $S=S^{-1}$ sometimes (actually almost always) people call the undirected, uncolored version, the "Cayley diagram".

Now if you take $G=\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $S=\{1,-1\}$, then your diagram is the Cayley diagram of $(G,S)$ in the undirected uncolored sense.

However, if you insist on either the colored or directions then that diagram, since it has neither direction nor color cannot be a valid Cayley diagram.

Comment: It is explained in the book that undirected lines do imply that the element is its own inverse - does that mean that in order for this diagram to be valid I should assume they ignored the colour?

Answer (score 0):

The diagram you showed has *bi*directional edges.  That implies that the *generator* they represent is its own inverse. 
But if the generator were its own inverse it couldn’t generate the 6 *different* states depicted on its own.

Therefore the 6-cycle you’ve shown needs *uni*directional edges.

---

The key here is that edges in Cayley diagrams only represent *generators* and any *generator* of a cycle bigger than two must be unidirectional even though the group actions are all invertible.
(If we showed all the edges that connect nodes we’d have to connect each node [a “complete graph”, of your familiar with that vocabulary], which would be difficult to parse.)